# Call another function and optionally keep default arguments

Tags: python

I have a function with one optional argument, like this:

```
def funA(x, a, b=1):
   return a+b*x
```

I want to write a new function that calls `funA` and also has an optional argument, but if no argument is passed, I want to keep the default in `funA`.

I was thinking something like this:

```
def funB(x, a, b=None):
   if b:
     return funA(x, a, b)
   else:
     return funA(x, a)
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Why not setting the default value for `b` in `funB` and then always send with `b` parameter to `funA()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would replace `if b` with `if b is not None`, so that if you pass `b=0` (or any other "falsy" value) as argument to `funB` it will be passed to `funA`.

Apart from that it seems pretty pythonic to me: clear and explicit. (albeit maybe a bit useless, depending on what you're trying to do!)

A little more cryptic way that relies on calling `funB` with the correct keyword arguments (e.g. `funB(3, 2, b=4)`:

```
def funB(x, a, **kwargs):
    return funA(x, a, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The cryptic way is a step backwards. Harder to read with no gain in functionality.

Comment: Yes, you are right ("cryptic" rarely indicates something positive) and it also isn't really the same thing functionally, but still something that may be useful and avoid a lot of code in some situations, probably not this one. But it starts to be convenient if, instead of 1, we have 2,3,4... optional default arguments

Comment: @falsetru that's why I specified "that relies on calling `funB` with the correct keyword arguments"

Comment: The "cryptic" way is better if you ever use multiple inheritance since you may not know all of the arguments.

Answer (score 7):

```
def funA(x, a, b=1):
    return a+b*x

def funB(x, a, b=1):     
   return funA(x, a, b)
```

Make the default value of `b=1` in `funB()` and then pass it always to `funA()`

Comment: I can't change `funA`. Take it as given.

Comment: No need to change `funA()` if you don't want to.

Comment: @itzy if the default of funB is the same as the default of funA this is a good solution

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't clear on this in the question: I don't know what the default argument to `funA` is. (It's code maintained somewhere else that may change.)

Comment: I would make `funB` independent of the actual default value used by `A`. Ideally, you don't want to change `funB` if `funA` chooses a different default.

Answer (score 3):

The way you did it is fine. Another way is for `funB` to have the same defaults as `funA`, so you can pass the same parameters right through. E.g., if you do `def funB(x, a, b=1)`, then you can always call `return funA(x, a, b)` just like that.

For simple cases, the above will work fine. For more complex cases, you may want to use `*args` and `**kwargs` (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)). Specifically, you can pass in all your keyword arguments as a dictionary (conventionally called `kwargs`). In this case, each function would set its own independent defaults, and you would just pass the whole dictionary through:

```
def funA(x, a, **kwargs):
   b = kwargs.get("b", 1)
   return a+b*x

def funB(x, a, **kwargs):
   return funA(x, a, **kwargs)
```

If `kwargs` is empty when passed to `funB` (`b` is not specified), it will be set to the default in `funA` by the statement `b = kwargs.get("b", 1)`. If `b` is specified, it will be passed through as-is. Note that in `funB`, you can access `b` with its own, independent default value and still get the behavior you are looking for.

While this may seem like overkill for your example, extracting a couple of arguments at the beginning of a function is not a big deal if the function is complex enough. It also gives you a lot more flexibility (such as avoiding many of the common [gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)).

Answer (score 2):

Using [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec), you can get the default values (fourth item of the returned tuple = `defaults`):

```
import inspect

def funA(x, a, b=1):
   return a + b * x

# inspect.getargspec(funA) =>
#     ArgSpec(args=['x', 'a', 'b'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(1,))
def funcB(x, a, b=inspect.getargspec(funA)[3][0]):
    return funA(x, a, b)
```

OR (in Python 2.7+)

```
def funcB(x, a, b=inspect.getargspec(funA).defaults[0]):
    return funA(x, a, b)
```

In Python 3.5+, it's recommend to use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) instead:

```
def funcB(x, a, b=inspect.signature(funA).parameters['b'].default):
    return funA(x, a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `FunctionType` from `types`, you can just take a function and create a new one specifying the defaults at runtime. You can put all this in a decorator so that at the point of where you write your code it will keep things tidy, whilst still giving the reader a clue about what you are trying to accomplish. It also allows the exact same call signature for `funB` as `funA` -- all arguments can be positional, or all arguments can be keywords, or any valid mix thereof, and any arguments with default values are optional. Should play nice with positional arguments (`*args`) and keyword arguments (`**kwargs`) too.

```
import inspect
from types import FunctionType

def copy_defaults(source_function):
    def decorator(destination_function):
        """Creates a wrapper for the destination function with the exact same 
        signature as source_function (including defaults)."""

        # check signature matches
        src_sig = inspect.signature(source_function)
        dst_sig = inspect.signature(destination_function)
        if list(src_sig.parameters) != list(dst_sig.parameters):
            raise ValueError("src func and dst func do not having matching " \
                "parameter names / order")

        return FunctionType(
            destination_function.__code__,
            destination_function.__globals__,
            destination_function.__name__,
            source_function.__defaults__, # use defaults from src
            destination_function.__closure__
        )
    return decorator

def funA(x, a, b=1):
   return a+b*x

@copy_defaults(funA)
def funB(x, a, b):
    """this is fun B"""
    return funA(x, a, b)

assert funA(1, 2) == funB(1, 2)
assert funB.__name__ == "funB"
assert funB.__doc__ == "this is fun B"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
def funA(x, a, b=1):
   return a+b*x

def funB(x, a, b=None):
   return funA(*filter(lambda o: o is not None, [x, a, b]))
```

Version which will not fail if x or a are None:

```
def funB(x, a, b=None):
    return funA(*([x, a]+filter(lambda o: o is not None, [b])))
```

Comment: What, why?! I assume x, a and b must always be passed to x, a and b, not "take the non None values and pass them to the underlying function completely disregarding what/where each parameter is"